# How to store a binary file in an ios app made with unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binary

I'm making a game with levels, to store which level the user has reached, I used a binary file. The problem is, when I run it inside of unity, it works perfectly fine.

However, when I build it for IOS, there appears to be an error saying that my binary file has not been found:

```
Save file not found in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/35DB4F8D-9528-4178-908F-7C3F5F7E6A69/Documents/binary.file
```

This is the code that writes this file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void SavePlayer (Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/binary.file";

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();

    }

    public static PlayerData LoadPlayer ()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/binary.file";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;


        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        } 
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error because I would really like to publish my game when it is finished and I won't be able to do that until this error is fixed.

Thank you in advance

Emiel

Comment: You should add the code that writes and reads the file to your question.

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code shown, the file name is different, and the file name doesn't match between the two functions.  With the inconsistency it's hard to know if you have an actual code problem or just a typo. The question should include the *actual code* you're running when you have the issue. You should also look at `Path.Combine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your save file and your load file have different names, one of them is **binary.file** and the other one is **player.fun**. Shouldn't these two be the same name? Also insted of using **/** as directory separator:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
```

you better use this:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "player.fun";
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to change that one, I named it player.fun everywhere but it sounds a bit weird so I changed it stackoverflow only. But in my code it is player.fun